# How to run a http server on EMR master node of a Spark application

Tags: apache-spark, http, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr

I have a Spark streaming application (Spark 2.4.4) running on AWS EMR 5.28.0. In the driver application on master node, besides setting up the spark streaming job, I am also running a http server (Akka-http 10.1.6) which can query the driver application for data, I bind to port 6161 like the following:

```
val bindingFuture: Future[ServerBinding] = Http().bindAndHandle(myapiroutes, "127.0.0.1", 6161)

try {
      bindingFuture.map { serverBinding =>
        log.info(s"AlertRestApi bound to ${serverBinding.localAddress}")
      }
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception  => {
        log.error(s"Failed to bind to 127.0.0:6161")
        system.terminate()
      }
    }
```

then I start spark streaming:

`ssc.start()`

When I test this on local spark, I am able to access http://localhost:6161/myapp/v1/data and get data from spark streaming, everything is good so far.

However, when I run this application in AWS EMR, I could not access port 6161. I ssh into the driver node and try to curl my url, it gives me error message:

```
[hadoop@ip-xxx-xx-xx-x ~]$ curl http://xxx.xx.xx.x:6161/myapp/v1/data

curl: (7) Failed to connect to xxx.xx.xx.x port 6161: Connection refused
```

when I look into the log in the driver node, I do see the port is bound (why the host shows 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0? I don't know, that is the way in my dev testing, and it works, I see the same log and able to access the url):

```
20/04/13 16:53:26 INFO MyApp: MyRestApi bound to /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:6161
```

So my question is, what should I do so that I can access the api at port 6161 on the driver node? I realize Yarn resource manager may be involved but I know nothing about Yarn resource manager to point myself where to investigate.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are mentioning 127.0.0.1 as the host name or 0.0.0.0??

127.0.0.1 will work in your local system but **not in AWS** as it is loopback address. In such case you need to use 0.0.0.0 as the host name

Also make sure that ports are open and access is provided from your IP. To do that, go to Inbound rules for your instance and add 6161 under custom TCP rule if not done already.

Let me know if this makes any difference

Comment: I had used 0.0.0.0 before, it did not work. Also does inbound rules matter if I ssh into the master node and ran curl command there?

Comment: If I copy my application jar file to the master node directly under /home/hadoop, and run java -cp ./myApplication.jar com.mycompany.myapp.http.MyHttpServer, I see the port bound and I can access the url successfully, both from curl and on a browser. So the problem is when I start the Http Server from the EMR Step, something does not go as expected, even though the log says the port is bound successfully

Comment: Another thing, the step is spark-submit with parameter --deploy-mode,cluster. I read that in cluster mode, the driver runs inside the Yarn Container, so I am guessing port 6161 is bound for inside yarn container, and we need to expose that and map to port 6161 on the master node, just like docker run -p 6161:6161. Question is how can I do that?

Comment: I changed deployment-mode from cluster to client, now I can access the api! So in cluster mode, the driver is running inside the yarn container, the port is not mapped externally, causing it not accessible. In client mode, driver is directly running on the client outside the yarn container, hence we can access the port directly. The question remains for cluster mode, how do we do the port mapping for the yarn container